# Finding object in ListViewRow

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've assembled the following code in order to find an object in a ListView. I currently use this to return a TextBox on the ListViewRow that the user has selected.

```
private T findObjectInListView<T>(ListView lv, object item, string objectName)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

        // Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
        ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(lvi);

        // Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
        DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;

        //Cast to chosen type and return
        return (T)myDataTemplate.FindName(objectName, myContentPresenter);
    }
```

This works perfectly when my ListView only contains one DataTemplate, however as soon as I add another it fails. I imagine this is because I look I'm not looking for ContentPresenter by name, and consequently the first one is just returned (which in this case does not contain the TextBox).

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to solve this; am I correct in thinking I need to search for a ContentPresenter by name? I can't find any articles that address this issue so I imagine I may be on the wrong track altogether...

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
This is the xaml I am using. My function works fine when I remove the first GridViewColumn:

```
<ListView Height="372" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="516" MouseUp="listView1_MouseUp">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Check">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Quantity">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="0" Width="30" Name="quantity Foreground="LightGray" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Check}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Quantity}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="Column3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest strongly, that you perform your search on the data that is bound to the `ListView`!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. Excuse my ignorance, but could you elaborate a little? My textbox is added in the xaml and is not related to the bound data.

Comment: @Jon: I suppose you are showing bound data in the TextBox? If not, maybe you could show your XAML.

Comment: Unfortunately not; the TextBox allows the user to enter a quantity which I will process at a later date. I've updated my original post with the xaml. Thanks again.

Comment: You **should** bind that TextBox to your object and do the processing on that object. It simplifies things a great deal.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested and bound the TextBox to my object (a string in this case). However, the reason I'm finding the TextBox is not to get the data from inside - I'm actually locating it so that I can place the mouse cursor inside it. I believe this means that my issue still applies?

Comment: @Jonathan: Well yes, the problem still applies. What I suggest now, is just speculation and I don't know whether it will work or not, because I have never tried it: You could create an attached property `HasFocus` and call `element.Focus()` in the setter and return `element.IsFocused` in the getter. That attached property is part bound to a property in your object and then you would just have to set the property of your object to true.

Comment: BTW: All of my suggestions are based on the MVVM pattern.